# Return callback only after finishing all loop iterations

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, web

I am trying to return callback function only after all loop iterations are finished. I didn't find similar cases in google.

```
runProfile: function(env_id,profileData, callback){
        console.log('****envid: ' + env_id);
        console.log('****data: ' + JSON.stringify(profileData[0].title));        
        for(let i=0,validations = profileData[0].validations; i<validations.length; i++){
            console.log('$$$$$$ run validation ' + i +' ' + validations[i].command);
            var self = this;
            (function(index){
                self.runCommand(env_id,validations[index].command, function(res){
                    if(res.code===0){
                        validations[index].actual=res.data.trim();
                        validations[index].status = (validations[index].expected===validations[index].actual) ? "PASSED" : "FAILED";                    
                    }
                });  
            })(i);   
            console.log('finished index: ' + i);              
        }
        callback(profileData[0]);
        //    
    }
```

Comment: Adding `return` in front of `callback(profileData[0])` seems to resolve your question but I image there's something more you're trying to do here.

Comment: Convert your loop body into a promise function and use `Promise.all(validations.map(validationFunction)).then(callback)`.

Comment: @georg - i tried your suggestion it didn't work cause the validationFunction has it's own callback, the promise returned the callback before finished the validationFunction